# Can I remove System.Windows.Forms.dll referenced by protobuf-net

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, protobuf-net

I'm currently working to reduce the final build size of an APK produced from Unity

From the Unity Editor Log, I found some unnecessary DLL files. The largest one is `System.Windows.Forms.dll, referenced by`protobuf-net`.

The hierarchy is: `protobuf-net -> System.ServiceModel -> System.Messaging -> System.Windows.Forms`

Why does protobuf-net reference windows specific assembly?

How can I remove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `System.Windows.Forms` isn't actually Windows specific in Unity's case. Unity is using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) (open source implementation of Microsoft's .NET Framework) in the background, and it's fully cross-platform. The name of the dll is `System.Windows.Forms` just to keep Mono compatible with Microsoft's .NET Framework implementation.

Here's more information about [Mono's WinForms implementation](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/) if you're interested.

Protobuf-net uses `System.Messaging` internally, which means that `System.Windows.Forms` will also be included. When looking at the source code of Mono's `System.Messaging` implementation, I see at least two references to `System.Windows.Forms` in [MessageQueue.resx](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Messaging/System.Messaging/MessageQueue.resx) and [Message.resx](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Messaging/System.Messaging/Message.resx).

Also in the makefile of Mono's `System.Messaging`, you can see the following code:

```
ifdef NO_WINFORMS_DEPENDENCY
LIB_MCS_FLAGS += -d:NO_WINFORMS_DEPENDENCY
else
LIB_REFS += System.Windows.Forms
endif
```

To sum it up, I don't think you can get rid of the assembly. I'm not really familiar with Unity but looking at the sources of both protobuf-net and Mono, you'd need to build your own versions or do some magic to get rid of it.

**Edit:** I wonder if Unity has some sort of linking or assembly stripping mechanism built in? For example, when building an Android application I can use a linker which strips away all the unused methods, classes and other stuff from the assemblies I'm using. In your case only the small subset of `System.Windows.Forms` assembly that protobuf-net is using would be left.

**Edit 2:** [This](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html) might be something to look into, even though it's iOS specific.

Comment: thank you for your comment!, i'll check protobuf-net source code.